# How to put an "All" item into select menu of search toolbar?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have set up a `JQGrid` in my `ASP.NET MVC project`. My datasource objects have a `bool` property, which I want to search against with `JQGrid`.

I have set up a select menu in the filter toolbar, but I'm unable to place an `"All"` item in the first place, which would clear the filter on that specific column. The issue is that whenever I select `"Yes"` for example in one column, in the post parameters I always see a filter with value `"" or -1`, or whatever I set for the `"All"` option's value for all other boolean columns, which of course break the server-side search.

```
{ 
  "stype": "select", 
  "index": "Validated", 
  "searchoptions": { 
    "sopt": ["eq", "ne"], 
    "value": "-1:All;true:Yes;false:No" }, 
  "name": "Validated" 
}
```

And my post data:

```
filters: {"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"Activated","op":"eq","data":"true"},{"field":"Validated","op":"eq","data":"-1"}]}
```

On the server-side I have used Trirand's `ASP.NET MVC JQGrid` suite for databinding and automatic processing.

Comment: Have you tried an empty value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass the following as your search criteria for the dropdown it should work

```
:All;true:Yes;false:No
```

I also am using JQGrid and this satisfies my needs.

if you have the blank string it will not pass the criteria to the server side.

Comment: That's what I thought :P

Comment: Thank you that did the trick. I've only tried the "'':All;..." version (empty single quotes), what didn't work.